# How do I setup libxml in Eclipse Indigo CDT C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

This all is under Mac OS X 10.6 and the libxml libraries seem to be in /usr/local/libxml2/libxml, I added this to the GNU C++ support but still I get errors for the code that uses libxml. I couldn't find anything that explains what to do to get it working and my project to compile.

edit: Example errors

```
void printElementNames(xmlNode * a_node) {

}
```

This would give "Type xmlNode could not be resolved".

Comment: We need more information about the errors - and also how was libxml2 build as /usr/local/l is a non standard place

Comment: I edited my question and I haven't customly built it - it came like this with the Mac OS X I think.

Comment: OSX comes with NOTHING in /usr/local

Comment: Xcode puts nothing in /usr/local - but more to the point what #includes do you have ti use for libxml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got this here: [forum](http://groups.google.com/group/ns-3-users/browse_thread/thread/0a326dc49df69924?pli=1)

1. Right-click your CDT project and select *Properties*.
2. Expand *C/C++ General* and select *Paths and Symbols*.
3. Select *GNU C++* under Languages
4. Click *Add* to define new element
5. Write in the Directory field /usr/local/libxml2/libxml
6. Re-build

Comment: Having looked at Marks comment above I don't know much about OSX just linux, you may need to install libxml2 and then use that path.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working in the Cygwin environment, on Windows 7 (64bit), using Eclipse Kepler CDT for C++.

In Eclipse, goto

> Project --> Properties --> C++ Builder --> Settings --> Tool Settings
>   Tab
>
> Cygwin C++ Linker --> Libraries

In the Libraries (-l) add the file: **xml2.dll**

In the Library search path (-L) add the path: **"C:\cygwin64\lib"**

> Cygwin C++ Compiler --> Includes

In the Include paths (-I) add the path: **"C:\cygwin64\usr\include\libxml2"**