# Adding libxml to Eclipse project in Red Hat

Tags: java, eclipse, redhat, libxml2

I have a simple C++ project set up right now, where I'm trying to include libxml2. Im running Red Hat 7. I've read through various posts regarding adding external libraries to an Eclipse C project, see:

- [How do I setup libxml in Eclipse Indigo CDT C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584139/how-do-i-setup-libxml-in-eclipse-indigo-cdt-c)

Most answers say to add a the library path to the GCC Linker or something along those lines. The problem is, I'm not entirely sure where my libxml2 is stored, though I am certain it's installed. None of my attempts so in adding the library path in the settings has worked. Here is [my query to see where libxml2 is installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llwQs.png) And here is [me just looking through my whole file system to find libxml2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JN5M5.png). I'm still fairly new to Red Hat, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

> ldconfig -p

to find out library locations, i.e. myn looks like this (fedora):

```
$ldconfig -p | egrep -i libxml
    libxml2.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libxml2.so.2
    libxml2.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libxml2.so
    libxmlsec1.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libxmlsec1.so.1
    libxmlsec1-openssl.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libxmlsec1-openssl.so.1
    libxmlsec1-openssl.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libxmlsec1-openssl.so
    libxmlsec1-nss.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libxmlsec1-nss.so.1
    libxmlsec1-nss.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libxmlsec1-nss.so
    libxmlrpc_xmltok.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libxmlrpc_xmltok.so.3
    libxmlrpc_xmlparse.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libxmlrpc_xmlparse.so.3
    libxmlrpc_util.so.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libxmlrpc_util.so.4
    libxmlrpc_server_cgi.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libxmlrpc_server_cgi.so.3
    libxmlrpc_server_abyss.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libxmlrpc_server_abyss.so.3
    libxmlrpc_server.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libxmlrpc_server.so.3
    libxmlrpc_openssl.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libxmlrpc_openssl.so.1
    libxmlrpc_client.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libxmlrpc_client.so.3
    libxmlrpc_abyss.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libxmlrpc_abyss.so.3
    libxmlrpc.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libxmlrpc.so.3
    libxml++-2.6.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libxml++-2.6.so.2
```

Here is whole steps how to add:

1. Create new project using `new c/c++ project`
2. Select `c++ managed build`
3. Select `hello world c++ project`
4. Enter project name
5. Navigate to `properties -> c/c++ build -> settings`
6. Select `GCC C++ Compiler/Includes/Include Paths`
7. Add both path: `/usr/include/libxml2/libxml` and
   `/usr/include/libxml2`
8. Select `GCC C++ Linker/Libraries/Libraries`
9. Add `xml2`
10. Apply and Close
11. Re-Build project

Comment: Tried that, seems to not be able to find libxml when running:

Comment: Getting this error:
`Invoking: GCC C++ Linker`
`g++  -o "pchid_seeder_tool"  ./src/main.o   -lxml2`
`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxml2`
`collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`
`make: *** [test_libxml_project] Error 1`

Comment: @user7356447 if u have lib in /lib64 try adding this path into `Library search path`. If its freshly installed library run `ldconfig`

Comment: also make sure u have `/usr/include/libxml2` and `/usr/include/libxml2/libxml` check those folders exist

Comment: if they dont exist try to find via `find / -type d -name libxml2 | grep include` then replaces include paths with it, i guess u get the idea how does it work

Comment: If the /usr/include/libxml2 folders don't exist, you're saying I should make them? Because they do not seem to exist.

Comment: @user7356447 no need to make, just find it where it is via `find / -type d -name libxml2 | grep include` and add those folders instead default location. Do the same for lib path

Comment: Sorry, I'm a novice when it comes to C++. Thank you for the help btw. There are no include folders for libxml2 when I entered that query you posted, should I try to reinstall it do you think?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `libxml2.so` symlink which is only installed with the `libxml2-devel` package. Since libxml2 is in a standard location, you don't have to pass additional paths to the linker. If you include any of the libxml2 headers, you will have to add `/usr/include/libxml2` as custom include directory (option `-I`), though.

Comment: You are my hero! That was the missing piece. Combined with HRgiger's instructions, it's working now. Thank you so much.